# How to access a 'static' field of a child class in a base class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How to reference the attributes of a child class in a parent one?

I'd like to set up an object property from a class property:

```
class _CharField( models.CharField ):

    def __init__( self ):
        self.max_length = something.patterns_field[ 'max' ]


class EmailField(_CharField):   
    patterns_field = PATTERNS.EMAIL


class NameField(_CharField):
    patterns_field = PATTERNS.NAME
```

Instead of `somethind` in **__init__** I'd like a class object of a child class to setup a field of a child instance. I could use self as in my example but I think that's not quite correct.

How can I change my code?

Comment: You can use the class name, as in `C2.c`...

Comment: @l4mpi In a method of a base class? Sure?

Comment: In either case, this is a terrible practice. A Parent should have no awareness of its Children (in code, not in real life).

Comment: @sergzach doesn't change anything, it would work outside the base class too.

Comment: At least set `c = None` in `C1` so that all sub-classes will have *something* by default.

Comment: `c` is simply an abstract attribute of `C1` with no default value, making `C1` an abstract base class (in principle, if not enforced by the language) whose children must provide a value for `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably include c in the parent class (although you do not have to you should)

```
class C1:
    c=-1
    def output( self ):
        print self.c
        print C1.c

class C2( C1 ):
    c = "1"
    def C1output():
      print C1.c
      print self.c

c = C2()

c.output()
```

in your updated quesiton I think this answers

```
class _CharField( models.CharField ):
   def __init__( self ):
       #remember this calls with self as the child class 
       self.max_length = self.patterns_field[ 'max' ]
       #or for equivelent of EmailField.patterns_field (assuming you dont know EmailField) refer to self.__class__ 
       self.max_length = self.__class__.patterns_field[ 'max' ]
       #self.__class__ is the Class of the caller(in this case the child)
```

self is perfectly fine to use to read a static variable but if it has changed on the class you may not get the updated version

for example

```
class _CharField( ):
   patterns_field = {"max":-1}
   def __init__( self ):
       #remember this calls with self as the child class 
       self.max_length1 = self.patterns_field[ 'max' ]
       #or for equivelent of EmailField.patterns_field (assuming you dont know EmailField) refer to self.__class__ 
       self.max_length2 = self.__class__.patterns_field[ 'max' ]
       #self.__class__ is the Class of the caller(in this case the child)'

class EmailField(_CharField):   
    patterns_field = {'max':16}


class NameField(_CharField):
    patterns_field = {'max':12}

c  = _CharField()
print c.max_length1 # prints -1
print c.max_length2 # prints -1
e = EmailField()
print e.max_length1 #prints 16
print e.max_length2 #prints 16

n=NameField()
print n.max_length1 #prints 12
print n.max_length2 #prints 12
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Excuse me, my question was not clear. Now I have edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use a method as follow

```
class Parent(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.max_length = self._get_max_length()

  def _get_max_length(self):
    return None # or a value that would make more sense

class Child(object):
   def _get_max_length(self):
     return self.exact_value
```

Comment: Yes, I can. But I'd like to get it exaclty from a **class** field, not from a **method** and not from an **object** field.